# Wi-Fi Problem in I9001 Galaxy S Plus with CM11 ROM

Tags: cyanogenmod, wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-plus

I have recently installed [[GT-I9001][ROM][ION][4.4.4][KTU84Q] CyanogenMod 11.0 by ADC-Team - Release 17 [EOL]](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2579431) on my I9001 Galaxy S Plus. But after a while I found that my WiFi can't find any router around. Flash and reset factory doesn't works. How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution:

***Warning: You will lost all saved Wifi passwords!***

1. Install [Root Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.root.browserfree&hl=en) app.
2. After turning off WiFi, Go to `/data/misc/wifi/` and open `wpa_supplicant.config` with an editor and delete `network` section until end of file:

`// delete section:
    network={
        ssid="some wifi ssid"
        ...
    }`

save and close file.

3. Open Settings->Wifi (don't turn it ON!)->Advance (three vertical dots in button right) and open `Wi-Fi region code` and choose one of them, for example `United State`.
4. Now turn On your Wifi, so it should list all available networks around. Enjoy it! :)